# need help understanding ususual arithmetic conversions

Tags: c

This line I found in **c11/N1570** **6.3.1.8 - Usual arithmetic conversions**:

> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

Then I did test like this

```
uint8_t ui8 = 0xFF;
int16_t i16 = 255;

if(i16 == ui8)
    printf("%#.8X\n", i16);
```

According to my (obviously) wrong deduction herein `i16 == ui8`, `ui8` is implicitly converted to `int8_t` (according to the rule quoted above). After the conversion `ui8` equals `-1` so the `if` must "expand" to something like this;

```
if(i16 == (int8_t)ui8)
```

or

```
if(255 == -1)
```

which is not true. 
What bothers me is that after I ran the code the condition appeared to be true.
Can you please help me to understand what am I missing in the quote above?

Comment: An `int8_t` cannot represent all the values of a `uint8_t` (think of 128 and above), hence conversion to `int16_t` occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the signed operand `i16` in this case is `int16t`.  When the comparison is done, it is between an unsigned and a signed value. Since the signed type `int16t` is capable of holding all the possible values of `uint8t`, the `uint8t` value can be converted to `int16t`. So `FF` is implicitly converted to `255`, not to `-1`. This makes the condition true.

From Harbison and Steele's `C: A Reference Manual` 5e, p. 190:

> the general rule for converting from one integer type to another is that the mathematical value of the result should equal the original mathematical value if that is possible. For example, if an unsigned integer has the value 15 and this value is to be converted to a signed type, the resulting signed value should be 15 also.

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand what is occurring here. When you declare:

```
uint8_t ui8 = 0xFF;
int16_t i16 = 255;
```

both `ui8` and `i16` have their first 8-bits set. In both cases, their value is `255`. You can easily check this is the maximum for an unsigned 8-bit value:

```
char - signed       :        -128  to  127
char - unsigned     :           0  to  255
```

The problem arises here:

```
if(i16 == (int8_t)ui8)
```

When `ui8` is promoted to `int16_t`, **sign-extension** occurs (which extends the left-most bit in `ui8` duplicating it across bits 8-15 during the conversion. This leaves you with an `int16_t` representation of `ui8` being a negative value which causes the above comparison to succeed, (but for the wrong reason). You must be very careful when mixing signed/unsigned values for this reason.

Comment: But that is not what happens; the comparison does work. The OP thought that the comparison would be `i16 == (int8_t)ui8)` but the actual implicit conversion is `i16 == (int16_t)ui8)`, because the type of `i16` is `int16_t`.

Comment: Exactly what I was saying, I just borked the fail  -- fixing. Thank you, good catch.